# Setting color using a string in Anylogic

Tags: java, anylogic

I would like to set the fill colour of a closed polygon in an agent using a string parameter (for example "cyan"). The string is read in from a database so it can't be read in as a Color type (at least it doesn't seem like I can). I have tried various options but usually get the following:

```
Type mismatch: cannot convert from String to Color.
```

The best that I have managed is to use the getStandardColor(index) command, where I can use an integer, but then I haven't been able to find the list of colours corresponding to the 140 standard colours.

Is it possible to set the colour using a string type?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Check out https://help.anylogic.com/index.jsp?topic=%2Fcom.anylogic.help%2Fhtml%2Fpresentation%2Fcolors.html You can also create an Enum class with a Color type and a String property and return the corresponding Color

Comment: Thanks you, I'll have a look into it. I have also just realised after having a test that the index for the colours match the table in that help file. As a minimum I can use the index method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this:

```
Color color;
String yourColor="red";
try {
     color = (Color)Color.class.getField(yourColor).get(null);
} catch (Exception e) {
    color = null;
}
```

Comment: Thanks Felipe once again for the assistance.